# Python Scrape With Normal Chrome or IE Browser (Not Chromedriver)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using Selenium and Chromdriver which will load the site just fine including the Javascript loaded data.

My problem is a normal Chrome browser will update over time when this data changes and the Chromedriver holds the first static data it was sent. I haven't had any better luck with PhantomJS or firefox as a webdriver.

So is there anyway to use a normal Chrome browser? Or even IE?

I know *in theory* I could have it load a Chrome browser and watch the network traffic for the data I'm looking for but that seems pretty ugly.

I could have it constantly refresh the page but that doesn't seem neat and means more bandwidth usage and loading times.

I don't need it to be headless or have complex automation. Just load the page and let me read the updating data rather than just whatever it first saw.

I know Auto Hot Key supports this and that's my fallback at this stage. A macro script to dump the data into a file for Python to read.

Comment: It does use the actual chrome browser. You just have to grab the page content again after whatever data changed. If the page source is set to a variable before the new content is loaded and then used after the new content is loaded, the new content will not be there as the variable was set before.

Comment: Variable cleared and data grabbed again. In fact I've even sat with the browser open next to me normally opening a Chrome browser and one updated but not the other. Strange.