# How would I web scrape a visible website already open in regular google chrome with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, pyautogui

So, I need to scrape the eBay awaiting dispatch page to get the addresses of everyone who has ordered from me. To get to this page, I need to login. This is too difficult to do, due to the extreme robot detection eBay has in place. To login, I will use pyautogui to simulate mouse clicks and key presses. This will get me to the page I want to scrape. Now how would I scrape this page which is on my regular google chrome. Preferably, I want to do this in selenium, opening the print postage label links in new tabs, in REGULAR google chrome, not chromedriver, otherwise it would ask me to login again. How would I do this, even if it has to be done in BeautifulSoup. I have done some research and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804751/python-scrape-with-normal-chrome-or-ie-browser-not-chromedriver), which did not help me.